# How to call a function after final page is loaded in angular js

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

I have to call the Google analytic's track event method after the final page is loaded.

I have some internal state changes, which are getting tracked in analytics, which ideally shouldn't get tracked.

Ex: $state.go("programs_path") in some cases intern redirects to $state.go("home"). In this case I'm tracking both the state changes but ideally I have to track just the home.

I'm using

```
 $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
     //tracking code
    }
```

Can someone please suggest me some alternative. Thanks in advance

Comment: write a condition that excludes the states you don't want to track, does that makes sense?

Comment: In the above example I might need to track programs_path if it is not redirected to home page. In some cases it gets redirected and in some cases it doesn't. I need to track just the last redirected page always.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a redirect create another route with the same controller and view and add a dummy parameter or simple just modify the url, for example instead to redirect to "/home" redirect to "home/redirected" and don't track the redirected URL, just write a condition where you are handling the counters for page loads, it's not ideal but it should work

```
$stateProvider.
        state('root.home', {
            url: '/home',
            views:{
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'home.view.html' , 
                    controller: 'HomeController'
                }
            }
        }).
        state('root.homeredirect', {
            url: '/home/redirected',
            views:{
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'home.view.html' , 
                    controller: 'HomeController'
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But there are many places in my code where similar scenarios like above  holds. So I don't want to change any existing code. All I'm searching is for to call a function after the final page is loaded for the end user.